# Testing a ApplicationController before_filter in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I have an application that detects the subdomain on a request and sets the result to a variable.

e.g.

```
before_filter :get_trust_from_subdomain

def get_trust_from_subdomain
  @selected_trust = "test"
end
```

How can I test this with Test::Unit / Shoulda?  I don't see a way of getting into ApplicationController and seeing what's set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`assigns`](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/Test/Unit/Assertions.html) method should allow you to query the value of `@selected_trust`. To assert that its value equals "test" as follows:

```
assert_equal 'test', assigns('selected_trust')
```

Given a controller `foo_controller.rb`

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :get_trust_from_subdomain

  def get_trust_from_subdomain
    @selected_trust = "test"
  end

  def index
    render :text => 'Hello world'
  end
end
```

one might write a functional test as follows in `foo_controller_test.rb`:

```
class FooControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def test_index
    get :index
    assert @response.body.include?('Hello world')
    assert_equal 'test', assigns('selected_trust')
  end
end
```

Related to comment: note that the filter can be placed in `ApplicationController` and then any derived controller will also inherit this filter behaviour:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :get_trust_from_subdomain

  def get_trust_from_subdomain
    @selected_trust = "test"
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController
  # get_trust_from_subdomain filter will run before this action.
  def index
    render :text => 'Hello world'
  end
end
```

Comment: The before_filter is in my application controller - or are you suggesting that I setup a controller specifically for this test?

Comment: Not at all. You can put the filter directly in `ApplicationController` and the test should work just the same. `FooController` is just an illustrative example. Furthermore any controller that subclasses `ApplicationController` directly or indirectly will inherit this filter behaviour and you can test it in any related controller functional test.

Comment: Sorry to drag up an old thread, but I've been noodling with this as well. So the simplest route to testing `before_filter`s defined within `ApplicationController` is to just test them as part of the tests for one of the derived controllers?

Comment: I would think so. You would probably create a test controller class deriving from `ApplicationController` available just in the context of your test code specifically for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationController` is global, have you considered writing a Rack Middleware instead? Way easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted for this in another controller in the application:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  fast_context 'a GET to :index' do
    setup do
      Factory :trust
      get :index
    end
    should respond_with :success

    should 'set the trust correctly' do
      assert_equal 'test', assigns(:selected_trust)
    end
  end

end
```